# Need help replacing a specific column in a file by part of a column in another file in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have two input files as

File1 :

```
ABC:client1:project1
XYZ:client2-aa:project2
DEF:client4:proj
```

File2 :

```
client1:W-170:xx
client2-aa:WT-04:yy
client4:L-005A:zz
```

Also, array of valid values can be hardcoded like [W,WT]

Output :

```
ABC:W:project1
XYZ:WT:project2
```

SO basically, if the column2 of file1 matches any record's column1 in file2, then replace that coulmn2 in file1 by a part of column2 from file2.
TO obtain this part I need to split column2 in file2 using "-" operator and match the results against an array to determine valid values.

For the records not matching above criteria, they should NOT be displayed in the output.

I am new to shell scripting so would appreciate any help.
I have been trying since a couple of days and have been able to replace the entire column using

```
awk -F":" 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next}$2 in A{$2=A[$2]}1' OFS=":" file2 file1.
```

However, haven't been able to get the part of the column requirement working.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. Here is the `awk` code you're looking for, using the `split` function:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { OFS=FS=":" } 
  NR==FNR { split ($2,one,"-"); two[$1] = one[1]; next } 
  $2 in two { $2 = two[$2]; print }
' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
ABC:W:project1
XYZ:WT:project2
DEF:L:proj
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\([^:]*:\)\([^-]*\).*/s|:\1|:\2:|p/' file2 | sed -nf - file1
```

Explanation:

- `sed 's/^\([^:]*:\)\([^-]*\).*/s|:\1|:\2:|p/' file2` make a sed script that does the replacement.
- `sed -nf - file1` pipe it through to another `sed` instance and run against intended file

N.B. I don't understand `"Also, array of valid values can be hardcoded like [W,WT]"` so this may not fully suit your needs.